# Shadow or effect on image using css

Tags: css, reactjs

How can I achieve this shadow on this image like this?
[image: Ref 1]

My current image looks like this :
[image]

```css
.launchpad__imageDIV {
  padding: 38px 38px 18px 37px;
  position: relative;
}

.launchpad__image {
  width: 100%;
}

.refunks__desc {
  position: absolute;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  row-gap: 12px;
  bottom: 3%;
  left: 6%;
}
```

```html
<div className="launchpad__imageDIV">
   <img
      src={launchpadImage}
      alt="launchpad"
      className="launchpad__image"
      />
   <div className="refunks__desc">
      <div className="launchpad__refunk__class">REFUNKS</div>
      <div className="launch__live__class">LIVE</div>
      <div className="launch__desc">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, <br />
         sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore <br />
         magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud <br />
         exercitation.
      </div>
   </div>
   <div className="launch__learn__more">LEARN MORE</div>
</div>
```

I want a shadow on this image so that the text can be more visible. How can I solve this?

Comment: https://css-tip.com/gradient-overlay-border-image/

Answer (score 0):

With a background gradient that fades from black to transparent black. You can imagine `#a` to have an image in it instead of another gradient.

```css
#a {
  min-height: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #f00, #00f);
  position: relative;
  resize: both;
}
#b {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1.5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,255), rgba(0,0,0,0));
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div id="b">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Interesting text! Totally not an NFT or anything! Lorem ipsum, etc.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think your snippet and code would look clearer if you would use normal single color background for #a

Comment: It might, but OP also has an image for the background, not a single color, and I wanted to simulate something like that. Otherwise you could get the same effect with just a solid gradient.